# add span class beow a link img in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

This is what i get with this code, i have to use the Helper like this :

```
<li>
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('/images/home.png') . ' ' . __('Accueil'), array ('controller' => '/', 'action' => 'index.php'), array('class' => 'ajax', 'escape' => false)); ?>
</li>

<li><a href="/page/index.php" class="ajax"><img src="/CREAZ/images/home.png" alt="" /> Accueil</a></li>
```

I just want to add span class below the img src.

```
<li><a href="/page/index.php" class="ajax"><span class="home"><img src="/page/images/home.png" alt="" /></span>Accueil</a></li>
```

How can i do it ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('span', $this->Html->image('images/home.png'), array('class' => 'home', 'escape' => false)) . ' ' . __('Accueil'), array ('controller' => '/', 'action' => 'index.php'),array('class'=>'ajax', 'escape' => false)); ?></li>
```

Hope it helps.